# Getting Parent Element Width for Converter

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get the entire width for a current cell so I can draw a rectangle with a width of a certain percentage of that cell.  I wasn't able to bind to set the Width property more than once, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596377/set-grid-column-width-to-bound-perctange).  So my next attempt was to pass the grid with and UtilPct to the converter, subtract 150 (for the first column) and return my width.  However, the grid doesn't have a width, it just say NaN in Snoop and the actual width is 0?

What is the best way to get the actual calculated width of my cell so I can adjust the rectangle's width?  If anyone has any other approaches, I appreciated any help!

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icBrokerCreditList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BrokerCreditList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="brokerGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="utilCol" Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=BrokerName}"></TextBlock>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Rectangle.Width>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PercentageConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="utilCol" />
                                <Binding Path="UtilPct" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Rectangle.Width>
                    </Rectangle>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Why ActualSize is not updating its value on WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008525/why-actualsize-is-not-updating-its-value-on-wpf). ColumnDefinition does not inherit from FrameworkElement, so it's ActualWidth is not a DependencyProperty, meaning your binding will never be updated when it changes. You can use the ActualWidth of your TextBlock, however, as per [Robert Levy's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9008962/211627) suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ScaleTransform` for the `Rectangle`'s RenderTransform and bind the `ScaleTransform`'s X property to your percent instead of setting a Width.

Note: that would left-align the `Rectangle` because the `ScaleTransform` CenterX property defaults to 0. Unfortunately, it uses absolute values instead of percentages, so you can't use CenterX with an unknown width to right-align. <strike>You'll have to create a third column with a Width set to "Auto" and put the `Rectangle` in there.</strike> To right-align, set the RenderTransformOrigin to "1,0".

Note: if your percentage is in fact a percentage (i.e. [0-100]%, "55%"), you'll have to pass it through a converter to divide it by 100 to get a proper scale.